# Sending emails automatically at the click of a button

Tags: php, email, mailto

I am designing an Emergency Response page, and one of the features we need is to be able to click a button (e.g. 'Send details to embassy'), and then send an automatically-generated email to the intended recipient (`$email_address`) without having to go into Microsoft Outlook and click send. Is there a way to do this?

The only method I know is the `<a href='mailto:example@test.com'>` one, but this opens the email in Outlook and really I need it to be completely automated.

Comment: since you mentioned PHP, use PHP to do it, what you describe is a mailto link that is recognized by Outlook on a webpage not PHP code that shoots off an email/text/notice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this would work as a starting point:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Send details to embassy" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
{
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

**UPDATE**

This can be used as a Javascript function to call the mail.php page and send the email without reloading the page.

```
function sendemail()
{
    var url = '/mail.php';

    new Ajax.Request(url,{
            onComplete:function(transport)
            {
                var feedback = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                if(feedback.result==0)
                    alert('There was a problem sending the email, please try again.');
            }
        });

}
```

You'll need Prototype for this method: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request

I haven't tested this, but hopefully it should be along the right lines.

Comment: thank you! it's about 3 days I working for do this!!

Answer (score 1):

PHP supports sending email with the [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). You can find examples at the PHP documentation. (see link)

**Example from PHP documentation:**

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

// Send
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Rhapsody, this works well. The problem I have now is that when I use this method inside a mail.php file, and I submit the form then the page redirects. I need the page that I am sending the email from to be completely untouched because it has important stopwatches on it and these will be reset if redirected.

Comment: It's probably worth looking at making an Ajax call to the mail.php script, this would stop the page loading, but run the script.

Comment: Hi gmadd, would you be able to post an example of this please? I haven't had a chance to look into AJAX in much detail yet so I don't know how to do use it. Thanks

Comment: @user683526 I've updated my answer with some Ajax code, untested.